# python data.table windows build

Tags: python, windows, h2o, py-datatable

Has anyone had success getting the h2o python `datatable` package to install on Windows?  It requires clang/llvm (https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/wiki/Build-instructions), and the pre-built binaries for Windows are apparently insufficient when I tried. Thus it appears to need a full clang/llvm/llvmlite build from source to get working.  I'd love to see a detailed built process if someone has had luck.

Answer (score 1):

Datatable will officially release Windows wheels starting from version 0.11. Right now it is possible to install the development version of datatable by following the instructions at https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-on-windows